# Google Maps - SVG Marker Issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to get inline SVG's working on Google Markers, I have code that works fine, except when I try to set a fill on one of the SVG Shapes, using a hex code. The following function returns an SVG, that represents the marker we want to use:

```
function createPin(segmentDetail, lat = 0, long = 0) {
    const colour = segmentDetail.colour.toString().trim().toUpperCase();
    if (segmentDetail.colour) {
        return 'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8, \
        <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 36 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> \
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="11" style="stroke:white;stroke-width:2;fill:transparent;" /> \
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="11" fill="' + colour + '" /> \
            <path fill="white" d="' + segmentDetail.icon + '" ></path> \
        </svg>';
    }
}
```

On the second circle: `<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="11" fill="' + colour + '" />`  We want to set the colour based on a separate attribute, that gets determined at the time we place the marker.  If I use a colour in word format, such as:

```
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="11" fill="black" />
```

We get a black circle and everything works fine:

[image]

However, if I replace that with a hex code, it stops working, and I can't figure how to get around this.  I've tried setting the colour black to another string "findme", then using a regex replace on it, before I assign the icon in the mapping code, but that doesn't work.

Has anyone ran into this?

This is how I'm mapping the markers:

```
const icon = {
    url: createPin(_mapData[index][i]),
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 1
};

markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
        lat: _mapData[index][i].coordinate[1],
        lng: _mapData[index][i].coordinate[0]
    },
    icon: icon,
    map: googleLayers[encodedIndex].map,
    zIndex: (encodedIndex.trim().toUpperCase() !== 'BASE') ? baseZ + 10 : baseZ
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, never came across that post well duckduckgo'ing the problem, seems very obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by geocodezip, you have to escape the #, which I'm a bone head for not thinking of earlier, when you use encodeURIComponenent on the hex code, it takes care of that and fixes the problem.

For future reference if someone runs into this problem, the marker mapping code would become:

```
function createPin(segmentDetail, lat = 0, long = 0) {
    const colour = segmentDetail.colour.toString().trim().toUpperCase();
    if (segmentDetail.colour) {
        return 'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8, \
            <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 36 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> \
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="11" style="stroke:white;stroke-width:2;fill:transparent;" /> \
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="11" fill="' + encodeURIComponent(colour) + '" /> \
                <path fill="white" d="' + segmentDetail.icon + '" ></path> \
            </svg>';
    }
}
```